# Problema com encoding em leitor de arquivo Excel para Java

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Estou com um problema relativamente "comum". Tenho um programa em Java que faz a importação de uma planilha Excel e um dos campos de coluna possui palavras com acentos, cedilhas, etc.

Na hora de ler a variável, sempre está marcando com um losango preto nestes caracteres especiais.
já tentei algumas soluções com `normalizer`, `getBytes()` com todas codificações possíveis e tentei usar algo assim:

```
WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();  
ws.setEncoding("Cp1252");
```

Mas nada resolveu :(

O principal do código (para entender o problema) é:

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(diretorio,v_arquivo));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
Cell[] celula;

for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++){
        celula = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (celula.length > 0){
            evento = celula[7].getContents().trim(); 
        }
}
```

E minha String de evento aparece como por exemplo lacta??o
Grato pela atenção.

ps: Sou novo no fórum, ainda estou aprendendo as formatações, desculpem os possíveis erros.

Comment: O POI deveria tratar isso automaticamente. O arquivo XLS foi gerado como? Será que não está errado? Você pode compartilhar um arquivo do Excel que não funciona?

Comment: O arquivo xls foi gerado à partir dos dados de teste de um banco de dados (mas na hora de colar os dados eu utilizei até bloco de notas pra remover possíveis formatações do próprio banco). Vou ver se consigo gerar algum arquivo que possa ser compartilhado.

Answer (score 2):

Galera, ninguém comentou mas se alguém tiver esse problema futuramente, vou deixar o que encontrei registrado aqui (Consegui contornar o problema de certa forma). No caso de usar essa variável em qualquer consulta SQL (que era o meu problema, por não ser compatível com possíveis selects com o banco) eu usei a seguinte função:

```
public static String formatString(String s) {  
        String temp = Normalizer.normalize(s, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD);  
        return temp.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]","%");  
}
```

O que é feito: Apenas substitui-se caracteres especiais por "%", com isso, ao executar uma consulta SQL a palavra será encontrada normalmente na tabela.
Mas como disse, é apenas um contorno para o problema... não é uma solução :x